# Missing network drivers for Dell Dimension 4550

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, dell-dimension

I just reinstalled Windows XP Home for a Dell PC, Dimension 4550.  My problem is that I am unable to connect to the internet, even though the ethernet is connected and lit up.

I checked my device mananger and I am missing (yellow question mark) the following 2 drivers:

1. ethernet controler,Location: `BUS 2, DEVICE 8 FUNCTION 0`
2. USB device, location 0 (USB device)

Since I no longer have the installation CD that came with my PC, I went to the dell.com website and downloaded and installed the drivers

- R56237
- R56238
- R60203

to no avail and I am still unable to connect to the internet.  I am hopeing that someone can tell me which driver to download in order for me to get internet access via my ethernet/router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading/installing the two drivers listed for wired Ethernet, the Broadcom driver (look like you already did this one) and the Intel driver (R52043).

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply.  I  tried that to no avail and am still having the same yellow questin marks. please advise

Comment: What is the service tag for this PC? (there should be one or two stickers on the case)